# eclipse oxygen with google cloud sdk, not able to deploy to application

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I have updated Eclipse to the newer Oxygen release, followed all of these instructions ( https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart )  and i'm able to run my old projects in the development server locally just fine but when I try and deploy using 'Google appengine standard' option in Eclipse, the project it comes up with this error:

> Unable to stage:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to
>   compile jsp files.    at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:1177)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.populateStagingDirectory(Application.java:904)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:809)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplication(AppAdminImpl.java:539)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplicationWithDefaultResourceLimits(AppAdminImpl.java:492)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$StagingAction.execute(AppCfg.java:2510)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:393)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:216)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:116)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:112)
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to stage app:
>   Failed to compile jsp files.  at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplication(AppAdminImpl.java:543)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplicationWithDefaultResourceLimits(AppAdminImpl.java:492)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$StagingAction.execute(AppCfg.java:2510)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:393)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:216)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:116)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:112)
>   Caused by: com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException:
>   Failed to compile jsp files.  at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:1177)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.populateStagingDirectory(Application.java:904)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:809)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplication(AppAdminImpl.java:539)
>     ... 6 more

I have tried adding the old google appengine sdk's to the WEBINF/lib folder, but this has no effect.

The initial error in the console is:

> Beginning interaction for module default... 0% Scanning for jsp files. 0% Compiling jsp files. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query$Filter at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source) at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(G‌​enerator.java:1218)

Comment: the initial error in the console is:

Comment: Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Scanning for jsp files.
0% Compiling jsp files.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query$Filter
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1218)

Comment: Dont put more information into comments. Always update your question instead!

Comment: The Cloud Tools for Eclipse uses the project's configured Java runtime for the deploy process.  JSP compilation requires a JDK, and so my guess is that your project is picking up a JRE rather than a JDK.  Could you check that you have a JDK configured?  Use _Preferences > Java > Installed JREs_ and verify that you have a JDK, and then the _Execution Environments_ pane to ensure that the JDK is selected as the default project for JavaSE-1.7.  But deploying with a JRE should now fail with an error.

Please provide details so we can reproduce: what is project's `.classpath`?